# Translation suggestion for the experience part on Careers (French)

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization

I added and updated a job on my Careers page and I was surprised by a strange checkbox label:

> [image: Offre d'emploi publiée]

On the English version it's *Current Job*, but here it's *Offre d'emploi publiée* which can be translated as *Published job*. That's confusing. I suggest to replace *Offre d'emploi publiée* by *Poste actuel*.

Comment: That's a bug in translation, retagged.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion. Done!